# Is "fly like a bird" an example of collocation?

Tags: collocation, simile, literary-device

Is the simile phrase:

> flying like a bird

an example of collocation, with the close ‘expected’ relationship between *flying* and *bird*?

Comment: no, it has nothing to do with it.  an example of collocation with "bird" would just be "big bird", perhaps.  with "flying", maybe "high flying".  it literally means nothing more than a pair of words that are often seen together.

Comment: I'm with @JoeBlow. Collocations usually occur in pairs. What you've got there is a plain old simile. Btw, something can also fly like an arrow, or an eagle, or even a G6.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OnlTrq6wLf0

Comment: @Joe Blow ODO's 'the habitual juxtaposition of a particular word with another word or words with a frequency greater than chance' allows for longer strings.

Comment: I don't think so really, but look at usage.  it's used to mean "stable marriage" "natty dreds" and so on.

Comment: [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/collocation) is even more definite: 'a word or phrase that is often used with another word or phrase, in a way that sounds correct to people who have spoken the language all their lives, but might not be expected from the meaning:' [English Club](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/collocations.htm) lists 'burst into tears' as an example.

Comment: @TusharRaj if this is not a common collocation then why don't we say "Fly like a bee" or "fly like an insect" or "Fly like a kite" or "fly like a plane"? We say "bird" because that is usually the first image that comes to our mind when we think of something flying, and there's also the oft said expression *"free as a bird"*. It's never *"free as an escaped convict"* :)

Comment: Melita, a [collocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation) doesn't have to have a close expected relationship, they just need to be commonly associated (often with a close relationship but sometimes just .. they just happen together a lot). Eg you say 'black and blue' (for bruises) the words go together (but you just don't say 'blue and black'). The words in 'information superhighway' are not related at all.

Comment: @Mitch "black and blue" is an example of [binomials](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=binomials), which are related to collocations but they're not exactly the same thing. Wikipedia provides this example  "strong tea", we don't normally say "powerful tea"  or "dark tea" although they have, arguably, the same meaning.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sure, a binomial is a kind of collocation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: _[Collocation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/collocation): The habitual juxtaposition of a particular word with another word or words with a frequency **greater than chance**._ Your explanation proves that the reason we say 'bird' isn't merely chance. So, it's not a collocation. Besides, I already game some other examples which work, even if yours don't. There's also 'fly like the wind'.

Comment: @TusharRaj fly and bird are *habitually* paired, it's not "only" by chance, and hence, the pairing, in this instance the simile,  *is* a type of collocation.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: No, no. I wasn't clear, perhaps. What I'm saying is that collocations do evolve by chance (randomly). 'Weather permitting' has no particular reason to be preferred over 'weather allowing', yet it has a [greater frequency](https://goo.gl/si2zyL) than expected (by chance). That's a collocation. 'Flying like a bird' has every reason to be preferred over 'flying like an insect'. Hence, in my book, it's not a collocation; but a simile (like others in your answer, which I +1'd)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, according to Google [Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fly%20like%20a%20bird%2Cfly%20like%20an%20eagle%2Cfly%20like%20a%20plane%2Cfly%20like%20a%20butterfly%2C%20fly%20like%20an%20arrow&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfly%20like%20a%20bird%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfly%20like%20an%20eagle%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfly%20like%20a%20plane%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfly%20like%20a%20butterfly%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cfly%20like%20an%20arrow%3B%2Cc0) the expression "fly like a bird" (blue line) is by miles, more common than "fly like a plane" (green line); "fly like an insect" (which turned up no results) and "fly like a butterfly" (yellow line). Tushar Raj's suggestions: "fly like an arrow"(purple)  and "fly like an eagle" (red) which fared slightly better than the former; however, neither came close to the OP's simile. Consequently, I'd say that *fly like a bird* is a very **common simile** *and* collocation of two words: *fly* and *bird*. It is so frequently heard and used that nowadays, many would classify it as a worn out ***cliché***.

[image]

Another Ngram shows the results in descending order using Google's [wildcard](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=fly%20like%20a%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cfly%20like%20a%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20bird%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20hawk%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20witch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20cloud%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20coward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20swallow%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20criminal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20thief%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20bat%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20scared%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cfly%20like%20a%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20bird%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20hawk%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20witch%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20cloud%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20coward%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20swallow%3B%2Cc1%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20criminal%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20thief%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20bat%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bfly%20like%20a%20scared%3B%2Cc0)

[image]

Interestingly, there was the simile "fly like a swallow" (pink line) which enjoyed its peak between 1887 and 1889. The results show different publications containing Honoré de Balzac's story *The Exiles*

> When the rustle of the Countess' approach was audible, a boatman suddenly stood up, helped the fair laundress to take her seat in it, and rowed with such strength as to **make the boat fly like a swallow** down the stream.

Richard Nordquist, noted linguist, writes

> [**collocation (words)**](http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/collocationterm.htm)
>   Definition:
>
> A familiar grouping of words, especially words that habitually appear together and thereby convey meaning by association.
>
> *Collocational range* refers to the set of items that typically accompany a word. The size of a collocational range is partially determined by a word's level of specificity and number of meanings.

Similar clichés using VERB+LIKE+A+NOUN are:

- cry like a baby
- drink like a fish
- eat like a bird
- eat like a pig
- fit like a glove
- fly like a bird
- grow like Topsy
- laugh like a drain
- sing like a bird
- sink like a stone
- smile like a Cheshire cat
- swear like a trooper
- swim like a fish
- sweat like a pig
- watch like a hawk

<sup>Source: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_similes)</sup>

Comment: This is very comprehensive, most informative. It is just what I was after. Thank you.

Comment: @melita if this is the case, would you mind accepting the answer? It's the check mark under the arrow, click on it and users will see that your question has been answered. Thank you.