# Opposite of collocation, set phrase, and so on

Tags: expressions, linguistics, phrase-requests

Some strings of words are importantly *different* from other strings. For example, they might be used way more often than synonymous strings which would seem to be equally good choices.

Wikipedia defines ***[collocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation)*** as

> a sequence of words or terms that co-occur more often than would be expected by chance.

This is a pretty good definition, although "the" and "man" certainly co-occur more often than they would if language were a genuinely chance grabbing of words from a bag. By the above definition, "the man" counts as a collocation. I think this is undesirable.

Despite the imprecision of the definition, we all have an *intuitive* idea of what a collocation is. It's a ***common phrase***. Some people use ***set phrase***, ***fixed expression***, and even ***idiom*** (sense 1.1, [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/idiom)) in this way, meaning "common phrase".

On this understanding, all these terms mean something like "a form of expression that comes more naturally to, or is more popular among, a large subset of speakers than a synonymous expression". On this definition, "tall, dark, and handsome" counts as a collocation/set phrase/fixed expression/idiom.

I am not interested in formulating a precise definition of this concept, nor am I looking for precise criteria to differentiate, say, a collocation from a non-collocation. I am fine stopping at intuition, and boundaries, like peaches, are sometimes fuzzy.

But is there a term for the opposite of a collocation or common phrase? That is, is there a concise or canned way to describe a string like "birds fly overhead", a mere output of the normal combinatorics of language? Is there a word which describes, as @Drew puts it, [***"common words put together in an ordinary way"***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343983/where-does-the-phrase-frugal-new-englander-come-from#comment795067_343983)?

The reason I ask is because this site sometimes gets questions like

> - Who coined the phrase "the dog"?
> - What is the origin of the phrase "fly like a bird"? (cf. [***here***](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251719/is-fly-like-a-bird-an-example-of-collocation))
> - What is the first occurrence of the phrase "in the back of the house"?

I always struggle in expressing the idea that these are not set phrases, that they were not "coined", that they were likely invented simultaneously by a hundred people, and re-invented by a billion more.

What would you call such strings?

***[Compositional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom#Compositionality)*** doesn't quite work since phrases like "tall, dark, and handsome" are both compositional and set phrases. ***[Plain language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_language)*** doesn't quite work for the same reason, "tall, dark, and handsome" is both plain as well as a set phrase.

I am looking for nouns, adjectives, or whole phrases which can be used to describe such strings, so I am flexible. That said, here are some example sentences:

> - "In the back of the house" is not a collocation, it's a ___.
> - "In the back of the house" is not a set phrase, it's ___.
> - "In the back of the house" is not a common phrase, it's ___.

Comment: Yes. Utterances that are non-idiomatic, but rather normal, are called [***Compositional***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idiom#Compositionality). I.e, their meaning can be understood by composing the meanings of their constituents -- thus _Bill kicked the ball_ is compositional, while _Bill kicked the bucket_ is not.

Comment: @JohnLawler, In my question I was using *idiom* in its looser sense of "a form of expression natural to a language, person, or group of people" (ODO). Whereas "tall, dark, and handsome" is idiomatic, "tall, mysterious, and good-looking" is __. Both are compositional. Maybe *non-idiomatic* is the closest word.

Comment: Plain language? : 
Plain language is writing designed to ensure the reader understands as quickly, easily, and completely as possible. Plain language strives to be easy to read, understand, and use.It avoids verbose, convoluted language and jargon.

Comment: @Josh61, interesting suggestion, and it works for some cases. But "tall, dark, and handsome" is still plain language, despite being a fixed expression. So *plain language* and *collocation/set phrase/fixed expression* are *not* mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Silenus A definition like "a form of expression natural to a language, person, or group of people" is useless because "natural" is a judgement without standards or criteria.

Comment: @Silenus - any set phrase, even the one you cite, is not plain language if it carries idiomatic meaning and usage which require a deeper knowledge to understand it fully.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Don't you have the intuition that "tall, dark, and handsome" comes more naturally to you than "tall, mysterious, and good-looking"? The former expression comes more naturally to English speakers than the latter, as a rule. It's more readily employed. Although "natural" is, of course, vague. But lots of the concepts we use in theorizing are vague.

Comment: I will edit the question to make it clear that by idiom I do *NOT* mean an expression whose actual meaning outstrips its compositional meaning.

Comment: @Silenus - but would that be an idiomatic expression?

Comment: _Tall, dark, and handsome_ is a common phrase, like _light of day_ or _end in tears_. It's not an idiom, though, just a phrase that's become popular in the last couple centuries. Some phrases are more popular than others, but popular does not mean natural. That's a judgement, not a determination. And if a concept used in theorizing is vague, you're not theorizing; you're free-associating.

Comment: @JohnLawler, fair enough re: popular. But here's a theory: *bald men are generally less happy than luxuriously haired men*. Despite the fact there's no precise boundary between baldness and luxuriously-haired-ness (i.e. it's vague), it still counts as a theory. But that's beside the point.

Comment: It's not a theory; it's a hypothesis, and it depends on operational definitions of bald and haired (with no doubt a continuous cline between), to correlate with happiness (similarly defined operationally, with a cline). All that stuff would have to be in a theory. Hypotheses are just "suppose that ..." statements.

Comment: In any event, evolutionary biologists, quantum physicists, and pure mathematicians studying number *theory*, regularly employ vague terms in their papers. That's why I said "lots of concepts we use in theorizing are vague." Most of language is vague, after all. So it's unavoidable. But I think we're just semantically quibbling...

Comment: Instead of *co-occur more often than would be expected by chance* (a lousy description, IMO), I would say *co-occur more often than not*, or more precisely, *co-occur at least as often as at least one of the words occurs otherwise. *Motley crew* is a collocation because it occurs at least as often as *motley* occurs without *crew*.

Comment: @Drew, yeah, that is definitely an improvement! But I'm not really worried about a perfect definition, as I point out. We all have an intuitive idea of what we mean by collocation. My question is what's the best way to describe the opposite type of thing. Is there a more concise expression than your apt ""common words put together in an ordinary way"? [*We're dangerously close to being consigned to chat...*]

Answer (score 2):

[The Wikipedia article on collocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation) makes salient points about how collocations are regarded:

> The processing of collocations involves a number of parameters, the
>   most important of which is the measure of association, which evaluates
>   whether the co-occurrence is purely by chance or statistically
>   significant. Due to the non-random nature of language, most
>   collocations are classed as significant, and the association scores
>   are simply used to rank the results. Commonly used measures of
>   association include mutual information, t scores, and log-likelihood.
>   Rather than select a single definition, Gledhill proposes that
>   collocation involves at least three different perspectives:
>
> (i) cooccurrence, a statistical view, which sees collocation as the
>   recurrent appearance in a text of a node and its collocates,
>
> (ii) construction, which sees collocation either as a correlation between a
>   lexeme and a lexical-grammatical pattern, or as a relation between a
>   base and its collocative partners  and
>
> (iii) expression, a pragmatic view of collocation as a conventional
>   unit of expression, regardless of form.
>
> It should be pointed out here that these
>   different perspectives contrast with the usual way of presenting
>   collocation in phraseological studies. Traditionally speaking,
>   collocation is explained in terms of all three perspectives at once,
>   in a continuum:
>
> '**Free Combination**' ↔ 'Bound Collocation' ↔ 'Frozen
>   Idiom'

[bolding mine]

So, at least traditionally. 'free combination' is the term for a (very) loose association within a string.

Comment: That passage suggests a conceptual link between (i), (ii), and (iii) and "free combination, bound collocation, and frozen idiom", respectively, which I fail to see. Still, *free combination* seems to work as a (fairly transparent, but somewhat opaque) descriptor of what I want. +1! *Accidental combination* and *incidental combination* could also work, I guess.

Comment: You may like to look through the [Collins Cobuild article on collocation](http://www.fi.muni.cz/~thomas/CCS/collocation.htm). They do not include colligations (eg _rely on, wait for, crowd of, cant help + -ing_) as collocations, and doubtless this would rule out 'the man' etc (as a 'determiner phrase' according to DP-analysis). They also rule out what they call  'lexical bundles',  but include 'fixed phrases' (though I can't see much difference).

Comment: Thanks Edwin, I'll take a look! Although, as I pointed out, I'm not too concerned with finding a precise definition of *collocation* which excludes "the man" and answers to all our intuitions regarding it. You could probably block such "colligations" by adding a clause to the effect that function (or syncategorematic) words (like 'the') are to be discounted.